# pyodbc - where to insert data?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble inserting data using pyodbc. I have my microsoft server details which I've added to the code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=INSERT IP NUMBER;DATABASE=INSERT DATABASE NAME;UID=INSERT USER NAME;PWD=INSERT PASSWORD')
```

I can connect to the server, however I'm not sure how to write to the table I've created. I have the following details:

variable_cars = "mercedes", "audi", "ferrari"

A table on the database called "tester."

And a column in the table called "car_brands"

I would I go about adding the "variable_cars" list to the column "car_brands" on the table? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
cursor.execute("insert into (tester, name) values ('car_brands', 'variable_cars')")
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

in between the server connection details and execution? Like so:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=INSERT IP NUMBER;DATABASE=INSERT DATABASE NAME;UID=INSERT USER NAME;PWD=INSERT PASSWORD')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.executemany("insert into tester (car_brands) values (?)",variable_cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your list of strings into a list of tuples:

```
variable_cars = [(i,) for i in variable_cars]
```

Then bulk insert to database table using [`.executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18):

```
cursor.executemany("insert into tester (car_brands) values (?)",variable_cars)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. The script didn't come back with an error either. I'm guessing this would also work if there was just one item in the string: variable_cars = "audi"

Comment: @ragnampiza: Did you commit using `cnxn.commit()` after doing the insert?  By default, pyodbc does not autocommit.